# Textfield jQuery Validate and Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, validation, autocomplete

I have a problem with jQuery validate plug-in. 
I have a form with a textfield who have one hidden textfield, one for the description, the other for the ID. 
For validate the textfield, we must have an ID and a description. 
For help the user, we have an autocomplete plug-in.
When I enter a correct suggestion and type on enter, it's works fine.
BUT when I click on the menu of the autocomplete, the error label appear. And if I click in the textfield and outside, the error label disappear.

I try to custom the onfocusout method but, all I test don't work.
The same problem appear.

Look at my configuration plug-in :

```
    $(document).ready(function() 
{
jQuery.validator.addMethod("city_id", function(value, element) 
{
    if ( $("#city_id").val() != '' ) {
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
})
$("#recherche_target").validate(
{
  rules: 
  {
   city_string: "required city_id"
  },
  messages: 
  {
   city_string: "Veuillez entrer une ville valide."
  }
})
```

Anyone have ideas on how resolve this problem ?

Comment: Which autocomplete plugin are you using? Jquery UI autocomplete?

Comment: Yes, it's jQuery UI Autocomplete.